# Python's json.dump() output seems not relevant

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I hope you're doing fine.
Recently I decided to tinker a little with JSON files, but was struck by problem.
I am not sure if I make some kind of a cardinal mistake, but whenever I try to convert
a dictionary/string variable to .json file, the output does not really look similar to
what I'm used to.
Here's the code:

```
dictio = """{"Forms": [{"Forms_2D": [{"Line": ["test": 0 ],"Square": ["test": 0 ],"Triangle": ["test": 0 ],"Circle": ["test": 0],"Rectangle": ["test": 0],"Parallelogram": ["test": 0],"Rhombus": ["test": 0],"Trapezoid": ["test": 0],"Hexagon": ["test": 0],"Octagon": ["test": 0],}],"Forms_3D": [{"Cube": ["test": 0],"Pyramid": ["test": 0],"Cone": ["test": 0],"Cylinder": ["test": 0],"Sphere": ["test": 0],"Ball": ["test": 0],"Cuboid": ["test": 0]}]}],"Calculations": [{"Irrational": ["test": 0],"Not_a_Number": ["test": 0]}]}"""
    
with open("info.json", "w") as file:
     json.dump(dictio,file,indent=4,separators=(',', ': '))
file.close()
```

The Output of the code above seems like this:

```
"{\"Forms\": [{\"Forms_2D\": [{\"Line\": [\"test\": 0 ],\"Square\": [\"test\": 0 ],\"Triangle\": [\"test\": 0 ],\"Circle\": [\"test\": 0],\"Rectangle\": [\"test\": 0],\"Parallelogram\": [\"test\": 0],\"Rhombus\": [\"test\": 0],\"Trapezoid\": [\"test\": 0],\"Hexagon\": [\"test\": 0],\"Octagon\": [\"test\": 0],}],\"Forms_3D\": [{\"Cube\": [\"test\": 0],\"Pyramid\": [\"test\": 0],\"Cone\": [\"test\": 0],\"Cylinder\": [\"test\": 0],\"Sphere\": [\"test\": 0],\"Ball\": [\"test\": 0],\"Cuboid\": [\"test\": 0]}]}],\"Calculations\": [{\"Irrational\": [\"test\": 0],\"Not_a_Number\": [\"test\": 0]}]}"
```

I thought the problem was related to the input file, so I made many
versions with either tabulations or "\n", but with no luck - the output was only altered
with additional "\t" and "\n" values between the keys and arrays within one line.
On another hand I tried to use json.loads and than add it to json.dump like this:

```
x = json.loads(dictio)

with open("info.json", "w") as file:
     json.dump(x,file,indent=4,separators=(',', ': '))
file.close()
```

But than again it fails instructing me that there is a problem with ',' delimiter:
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 42 (char 41)`

Please help me out :-)

Best Regards,
stackoverflow-User

Comment: JSON.dump takes a dictionary, not a string.

Comment: As mentioned, `JSON.dump` is doing exactly what you asked it to do: you gave it a string that was _already_ JSON, and it has turned that string into _its_ JSON representation. And now you have a double-encoded JSON string. So don't do that =)

Comment: Yeah but I thought the indent will change the look of the output, but it does nothing.

Comment: There are invalid values like `["test": 0 ]` in `dictio` variable, which is causing the error.

Comment: @Weqfreger yes, because a JSON string won't be indented, otherwise, it would change the data being serialized.

Comment: @MohitGoyal there is no error

Comment: @MarkRansom to be pedantic, it takes any JSON serializable python object, and writes a corresponding JSON representation to a file. A `str` object is perfectly JSON serializable, and it will be serialized to a JSON value happily, a JSON string. Of course, we can surmise the OP *meant* to pass a dictionary.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So, if I am not able to indent a JSON string, does it mean I would need to re-write the said string into a dictionary manually to make it work?

Comment: @Weqfreger you need to parse it first with json.load/loads()

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah, I was over simplifying because I'm on my phone.

Comment: @Weqfreger you are fundamentally misunderstand what you are doing with `json.dump`. For starters, the string you have is not valid JSON. But `json.dump`/`json.dumps` expects *a python object* and then *emits a valid JSON*.

Comment: The thing is, a Python `str` is a Python object that can be serialized into a JSON value, a JSON string. Which is what you are doing, but that is clearly not what you *mean* to do. Why don't you tell us, though, what you are *actually trying to accopmlish*

Comment: You say, "a dictionary/string variable" . No, you have a `str`. There is no dictionary anywhere in your code. It is crucial that you understand this.

Comment: Furthermore, `x = json.loads(dictio)` is not going to work, since `dictio` is a `str` that **does not represent valid JSON**. here is a python `str` object that represents valid JSON: `dictio = '{"a":1}'`; if you deserialize that string with `json.loads`, it will correctly emit a python `dict` with a single key-value pair, the key `'a'` and value `1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @juanpa.arrivillaga. The logic behind JSON functions in Python makes more sense to me now. I will try to implement the above and make some tests.

Answer (score 1):

`json.dump` takes a real dictionary as an argument.   You are passing a JSON string.

Comment: No, `json.dump` takes any JSON-serializable python object. This *could* be a `dict`, a `list`, a `str`, `int`, `float`, etc etc